# how to bind a constant to target component in angular2(dart)?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I'm following the tutorial here:
https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html

So I thought it would be possible to bind multiple targets:

**app-component.dart**

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero" [msg]="123"></my-hero-detail>
```

**hero_detail_component.dart**

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    template: '''
      <div *ngIf="hero != null">
        <h2>{{msg}} {{hero.name}} details!</h2>
        <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div>
          <label>name: </label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
        </div>
      </div>'''
    )       
class HeroDetailComponent {
    @Input()
    Hero hero;

    @Input()
    String msg;
}
```

So I noticed something obviously wrong.  Angular needs to distinguish between a property of the `AppComponent` (`selectedHero` in this case) and realize that `123` is not a variable, but a value I want to assign to `msg` property.

So the question is --- how can we pass a value to `HeroDetailComponent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to assign value `123` to `msg` property, not value of variable named `123`. There are two ways to do this:

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero" msg="123"></my-hero-detail> //first way

<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero" [msg]="'123'"></my-hero-detail> //second way
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks